# C++: Delete an array of pointers then re-construct with a new size

Tags: c++

I have question regarding the array of pointers in the C++. I wonder if it's safe to do this:

```
int *a = new int[4];
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
a[2] = 3;
a[3] = 4;
delete[] a; //release the memory
a = new int[6]; //re-construct with a new size.
a[0] = 5;
a[1] = 6;
a[2] = 7;
a[3] = 8;
a[4] = 9;
a[5] = 10;
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes, that's OK. But do consider using `std::vector` instead.

Comment: You aren't "re-constructing the array", you're constructing a *new* array. (`a` is *not* an array, but it points to one)

Comment: That's not an array of pointers. It's an array of `int`. And `a` is a pointer to that array.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your usage. In this example:

```
int main() {
    Your Code
}
```

It is safe, because after then end of main, all memory will be released by the OS. But if you do this:

```
int main() {
    while (true) {
        Your Code
    }
}
```

You are generating a memory leak, because you are not releasing the memory after re-initializing it. You use more and more memory and will eventually cause a failed `new[]` (Stack Overflow).

You should `delete` every object created by `new` (and `delete[]` every array created by `new[]`).

```
int *a = new int[4];
a[0] = 1;
...
delete[] a; //release the memory
a = new int[6]; //re-construct with a new size.
...
delete[] a;
```

But overall the benefit of c++ in this case is RAII (Resource acquisition is initialization) types. This means you should be using provided c++ types like `std::vector` which handle memory creation and deletion in a good encapsulated way.

Comment: "You should have a `delete` for every `new`" is, in general, not correct. More accurate would be "you should `delete` every object created by `new`"

Comment: @immibis Out of interest, can you provide an example where this is not true?

Comment: `void f(int *i) {delete i;}` `void g() {f(new i); f(new i);}` contains two `new`s and one `delete`, which according to the "one `delete` per `new` rule" means it leaks memory.

Comment: @immibis Yeah, you are right, same holds true for placement new now that i think about it. Fixed.

Comment: It also leads to code like `int f() {Thingy *t = new Thingy; /* do stuff */ return t->someVariable; delete t;}` - "I matched up the `new`s and `delete`s, what's the problem?"

Comment: @immibis yep, all good points. Changed now. Also in the above, impossible function, i think the return and delete should be switched. But i get what you mean. Ha ha, dangly parts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes is is. (If you delete a afterwards ;))

Comment: Yes the delete is required - the array needs to become larger

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's fine. The rule is that every `new[]` needs a matching `delete[]` (just as every `new` needs a matching `delete`).

Although, if I were you, I'd use a `std::vector<int>`, and call its member function `resize` as necessary. (Then you are less likely to have memory issues: note well that you're missing a final `delete[]`).